# Exception: [Status Code: PaymentRequired; Reason: To access this resource, the app must be associated with an Azure subscription]

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using Graph API for teams communication in my web application. We have azure valid subscriptions.In graph API i am using Model B as price model.

But now it's not working giving error like -

Exception: [Status Code: PaymentRequired; Reason: To access this resource, the app must be associated with an Azure subscription

Hello,

I am using Graph API for teams communication in my web application. We have azure valid subscriptions.In graph API i am using Model B as price model.

But now it's not working giving error like -

Exception: [Status Code: PaymentRequired; Reason: To access this resource, the app must be associated with an Azure subscription. without payment model, that is deafult model is working